# Photoshop: Adding a 10px margin all around a resized image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, margin

I was given the task to resize images to dimensions of 736 x 475, with a 10px margin all around for a buffer zone in case there's shadow in the image or something else.

I found [this](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Adobe-Photoshop-1028/2009/3/setting-margins.htm) tutorial for viewing the margin in inches. What I'm wondering is if there's a way to input 10px of margin (all borders) and have that area left as a blank area, instead of guesstimating what 10px would be in inches, using something like [this converter](https://www.ninjaunits.com/converters/pixels/pixels-inches/)?

Comment: Hi ebbfl0, thanks for your question. Your question isn't wholly clear to me. Can you [edit] your question to tell us what exactly you're having trouble with? If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could open up 'Canvas size' (Alt + Ctrl/Cmd + C), select 'Pixels' as the unit of measure, and increase width and height by 20px (10px margin on all sides).

Answer (score 1):

- Resize to 20 pixels smaller in each direction first.
- Then expand canvas outwards to the desired size with white background showing

Comment: I tried this approach as well (successfully) - thank you for your feedback!!